# How to tell Google Chrome to trust a particular HTTP site?

Tags: google-chrome

I have set up a local web server using IIS in my Windows 10 PC. The server is hosting web sites over HTTP protocol. But, I want to test some web APIs such as geolocation API and notification API, which the Chrome browser doesn't allow.
Since I do not have a HTTPS certificate, I can't host my site over HTTPS.
So, I want to ask, if there is any way to configure Google Chrome to trust a particular HTTP site and grant those special permissions to that site?

Comment: Some of the answers to [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7580508/1115360) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has become rather strict regarding websites without certificates.

The best solution would be to get a Free SSL/TLS Certificate from
[Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

You may also try to create a Chrome shortcut and add to it the parameter
`--ignore-certificate-errors`. If it works, Chrome will give a warning on starting,
but will at least open the website, perhaps more.